# How can I use sublime text on Lubuntu to run script directly by just pressin a key?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

On windows 7, this is the code I use saved as  python_run.py in packages folder

```
import sublime
import sublime_plugin
import subprocess
class PythonRunCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self):
        command = ['cmd','/k',r"C:\Python34\python.exe",sublime.active_window().active_view().file_name()]
        subprocess.Popen(command)
```

then the key binding:

```
{
    "keys": "f2"],
    "command": "python_run"
}
```

**Could someone help me do the same but on Lubuntu OS? I am new to linux.**

Comment: This question is not specific to Python. You may find much better luck if you ask it on a ubuntu-specific site, e.g., https://askubuntu.com/questions/15050/how-do-i-bind-sh-files-to-keyboard-combination

Comment: I'd also like to recommend [su].